# What is the correct term for the word "usage," as in "linguistic usage"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

What is the correct word in Spanish for the word "usage," in the sense of linguistic usage?

Answer (score 3):

English [*usage*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/usage):

> The action of using something or the fact of being used.

Spanish [*uso*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bBV63BI):

> The act of using [something].

Comment: Esta respuesta sería más útil si incluyera una frase como ejemplo, en un uso linguístico.  (Ja já, acabo de hacer un ejemplo por accidente.)